# Explore object at run time in C#, like showing quick watch?

Tags: c#, variables, reflection, grammar, watch

When I am running a C# code in debug mode. I can add objects to watch window and explore them, or I can view them in quick watch.

I am creating an application where I want to show user a window with an object, and he should be able to explore the shown object. Is it possible to have this using some existing API. Or I have an option of using any grammar explorer like [Irony](http://irony.codeplex.com/) to achieve the same.

Just in case you require more information regarding the application, I am creating some objects depending on users inputs and showing user the object created, which he can explore to check if everything is right, he can modify them if required, intended user-base for this application are developers itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you want the user to be able to explore the object data:**

You can use the [`ObjectDumper` class](https://objectdumper.codeplex.com/) that has been known to do that. I've never confirmed, but I've always suspected that the [Immediate Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy.aspx) uses that.

From the project site:

> ObjectDumper takes a normal .NET object and dumps it to a string,
>   TextWriter, or file. Handy for debugging purposes.
>
> This class library for.NET 3.5 and 4.0 enables you to take an object
>   instance and easily dump its contents to a string, Debug-output, a
>   TextWriter, or to a file. Handy for debugging purposes.

Or do it by yourself:

```
foreach(PropertyDescriptor descriptor in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj))
{
    string name=descriptor.Name;
    object value=descriptor.GetValue(obj);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}",name,value);
}
```

Comment: immediate window can only be used at debugging. But when user has this application installed immediate window is not available. Your second solution also does not give user an intuitive UI to explore objects. I want something like `Quick Watch` to be available to user at run-time (not at debugging)

Comment: Using the building-blocks which I provided you here, I believe it could be a good start to build such a UI "Quick-Watch" by yourself.

Comment: I have gone through ObjectDumper, it is not of our help, I already suggested in main question, `irony` is one of the possible solution. But I am looking for something which is natively available to me.

Comment: any idea is I use `irony` irony.codeplex.com for this, can that be successful.